# is the space of absolutely continuous functions complete

Tags: functional-analysis, absolute-continuity

The space of absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is equipped with norm $\|f\|:=|f(0)|+V_0^1(f)$.

($V$ is the variation, here is the definition if needed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation)

Check that this is indeed a norm and check if the space is complete.

I did the first part, I don't know how to prove it is complete or not...

Comment: I am guessing you are asking if the space is complete.

Comment: yes, I have another question with it being closed subspace and I made a mistake here, I'm sorry, here I'd like to know if it is complete

Comment: You can use completeness of $L_1[0,1]$ as part of the proof. If a function $f$ is ac. then $f(t) = f(0)+ \int_0^t f'(\tau) d\tau$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $f$ is ac. then $f$ is differentiable ae., $f' \in L^1[0,1]$ and
$f(t) = f(0)+ \int_0^t f'(\tau) d \tau$. We have
$\|f\|_{AC} = |f(0)|+\int_0^1 |f'(\tau)| d \tau$.

Suppose $f_n$ is Cauchy, then you need to produce a candidate $f$, show
that it is ac. and that $f_n \to f$ in the given norm.

Since $f_n$ is Cauchy, we see that $f_n(0)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$
and $f_n'$ is Cauchy in $L_1[0,1]$. Hence
there is some $f_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g \in L_1[0,1]$ such that
$f_n(0) \to f_0$ and $f_n' \to g$ (in $L_1[0,1]$).

Define $f(t) = f_0+\int_0^t g(\tau) d \tau $. Since $g $ is integrable, we see that $f$ is ac, and we have
$\|f-f_n\|_{AC} \le |f_0-f_n(0)| + \int_0^1 |g(\tau)-f_n'(\tau) | d \tau $, hence $f_n \to f$ in the given norm.