# absolutely continuous functions as a subspace of continuous functions with bounded variation

Tags: functional-analysis, absolute-continuity

The space of absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is equipped with norm $\|f\|:=|f(0)|+V_0^1(f)$.

Every AC-function is continuous with bounded variation, so it is a subspace of $C[0,1]\cap BV[0,1]$.

Is this subspace closed?

Comment: Which topology is on $C[0,1]\cap BV[0,1]$?

Comment: same as in the subspace, i.e. topology determined by the given norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a positive answer to [an other your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520208/is-the-space-of-absolutely-continuous-functions-complete), this space of absolutely continuous functions is complete, so it is closed in a metric space $C[0,1]\cap BV[0,1]$, containing it.

Comment: thanks, sometimes it happens to miss a simple fact... however it's interesting, that noone answered the question during over 3 days before